# Changing the memory location of constant pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I have program

```
void alloc(char **p)
{
     *p=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*3);
        (*p)[0]='a';
    (*p)[1]='f';
    (*p)[2]='\0';

}
main()
{
    char p[]="hrrgr";
    alloc(&p);

    printf("%s",p);
}
```

It prints nothing. Please explain this.
I know by passing char*p ; and alloc(&p) will do the trick. But the purpose of my question is to understand the output I am getting.

Comment: Arrays decay to pointers in certain instances but this is not one of those instances. Use char* instead.

Comment: I assume you saw the warning from the compiler that you're passing a `char (*)[]` for a parameter that's expecting a `char **`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p` is an array of 6 characters. Therefore `p` is of type `char[6]`. `&p` is then of type `pointer to char[6] type`, i.e., `char (*)[6]`. When you pass an array to a function, it evaluates to a pointer to its first element. Thus when you are passing a `char (*)[6]` type value to your `alloc` function, you are assigning a `char (*)[6]` type to a `char **` type. They are incompatible types and have different pointer arithmetic. You can't make `char (*)[6]` *behave* like a `char **` type, even by typecasting which will only suppress compiler warning.

Answer (score 2):

This is not allowed: `p` is an array of 6 characters, not a `char` pointer. You should not treat `&p` as a `char**` pointer.

If you want to fix this code, declare `p` like `char*`, not as an array:

```
char *p="hrrgr";
alloc(&p);
```

[Running demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/D4mRCC)

Comment: `p` is an array of `6` characters.

Comment: @haccks You're right, my count is off by one. Thanks!

Comment: attempting to change the string pointed to by `p` will cause undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

`&p` is of type `char (*)[6]` but your function `alloc` expects an argument of type `char **`. You are passing wrong type parameter.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
void alloc(char **p)
{
    *p=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*3);
    (*p)[0]='a';
    (*p)[1]='f';
    (*p)[2]='\0';
 }
 main()
{
   char *p;
   alloc(&p);
   printf("%s",p);
 }
```

When ever you declare an array then there will be continuous allocation of memory but here your are changing starting 3 elements memory which changes the whole location of array and printing garbage...